# Type 'CssFunctionReturnType' is not assignable to type 'InterpolationFunction<any>'.ts(2769)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-system

Recently, I am getting an error every time I try to use the css function from styled system.
It was working perfectly before without any erros. No i keep getting the error:

> Type 'CssFunctionReturnType' is not assignable to type 'InterpolationFunction'.ts(2769)

Here is the code snippet, where the error happens:

```
const FlexCol6Left = styled(FlexCol6 as any)`
  padding-top: 0;
  ${css({
    paddingLeft: ['0', '0', '0'],
  })}
`;
```

The rest of the error message:

> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 3, '(first:
> TemplateStringsArray | CSSObject | InterpolationFunction,
> ...rest: Interpolation[]): StyledComponent<...>', gave the
> following error.
> Argument of type 'CssFunctionReturnType' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Interpolation'.
> Type 'CssFunctionReturnType' is not assignable to type 'InterpolationFunction'.
> Type 'CSSObject' is not assignable to type 'Interpolation'.
> Type 'CSSObject' is not assignable to type 'string'.   Overload 2 of 3, '(first: TemplateStringsArray | CSSObject |
> InterpolationFunction, ...rest: Interpolation[]):
> StyledComponent<...>', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'CssFunctionReturnType' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Interpolation'.
> Type 'CssFunctionReturnType' is not assignable to type 'InterpolationFunction'.

I´m using **typescript version: ^4.0.3**

Answer (score 0):

so after some trial and error, I solved the issue by importing the types for styled-components using @types/styled-components.